# Permutations O level Photograph Seating Arrangement Problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Here is the problem: Mum and Dad and their 4 children are to take a family photograph. They are to sit in a row containing 6 chairs.
>
> Q: How many different ways of seating are there if Mum and Dad are to have exactly one of the children sitting between them?
>
> ANS: 192

What I've tried: $3! \cdot 4C1 \cdot 2!$ because I guess the 3 remaining children would be moving from seat to seat, so, 3! and 4C1 because one child will be picked from 4 and 2! because Mum and Dad would be changing places with one of the children between them.

The result I am getting is $48$ and it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let's start with the **M c D** group possible placements. (You can think of it as gluing the three together, so that **M c D** becomes one piece to place in four chairs - the other three chairs being occupied by the remaining children):

  1. **M c D** c c c
  2. c **M c D** c c
  3. c c **M c D** c
  4. c c c **M c D**

Four ways to place parents with one child between them; but also Mum and Dad can switch places. So we have $4\cdot 2! = 8$ ways to place Mum and Dad.

- In other words, we need also to count the following four placements (pasting together **D c M**), in addition to the first four placements we listed:

  1. **D c M** c c c
  2. c **D c M** c c
  3. c c **D c M** c
  4. c c c **D c M**

---

- With respect to which child sits between Mum and Dad in the eight possible seatings of the parents above, we have $\dbinom 41 = 4$ ways to select which child sits between Mum and Dad.
- And lastly, we have $3!= 6$ ways to seat the remaining three children.

**Therefore**:
That gives us $\;4\cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3! = 192\;$ ways to seat the family given the required conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much, you not only explained it very well but you also helped me enhance my knowledge on these two topics.

Comment: You're welcome, Ben!